# variable issue in codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables

I am trying to passing a value, something like `2:03`, in codeigniter controller function.  But it is not working.  If I send any int or char or something like `'2:03:56:45'` it works.

Can someone tell me please what is going wrong with '2:03'?

My code is here :

```
function get_value($point_code ){

    echo $point_code;die(); 

}
```

here $point_code is `2:03`

Comment: why are you using die and not return? Is this an ajax call or something?

Comment: Are you passing `2:03` or `'2:03'`?  If there is a colon in it, it needs to be a string (in quotes).

Comment: Define "not working".  Do you see the wrong data echoed?  No data?  An error?  What does it do that makes you think it's "not working"?

Comment: i am passing 2:03 . no it is not a ajax call. not working means no data printed and no error showing.

Comment: Please show the code where you call the function.

Comment: @Treadstone: Are you passing it as a string?  That's what I was trying to ask.

Comment: this is my actual code controller name is site                                               function get_sub_categories($category_code){
  
   echo  $category_code;die();
  $this->load->helper('post_helper');  
  $sub_category_obarray = load_sub_categories($category_code);
  
 }                                                                              i am trying by url     localhost/bp/site/get_sub_categories/2:03

Comment: So, you are trying to send `2:03` in the URL?

Comment: yes. i am. is there any problem to go with url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears there is an issue in CodeIgniter when the URI has a single colon followed by a number.

See:

- http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/183230/
- http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/183553/

The solution given in the forums is to modify `system/core/URI.php` and change

```
$uri = parse_url($uri, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

To:

```
$uri = urldecode(parse_url(urlencode($uri), PHP_URL_PATH));
```

This is line 219 in the 2.1.4 release of CI.

I was able to reproduce the issue and updating that line resolved the issue for me.

I really hate solutions that involve modifying the core files.